# Failed to build gem native extension when install RedCloth-4.2.9 install Linux

Tags: ruby, redcloth, octopress

I want to install `Octopress` in my computer.
I try to do it like

[Octopress document.](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/)

When I run

```
bundle install
```

I got error message

```
An error occured while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So, I run

```
sudo gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'
```

then, I got a error message again:

```
ERROR:  Error installing RedCloth:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I hadn't learn any knowledge about ruby.

Comment: What GNU have you? Have you build `dev` package for Ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've probably upgraded to `Mountain Lion` and have not rebuilt your `ruby-1.9.2` install yet with the new development packages.

```
rvm --force install 1.9.2
gem install bundle --no-ri --no-rdoc
bundle install
```

If you don't have the `Mountain Lion` dev packages installed correctly, use the [ThoughtBot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion) instructions.

Answer (score 29):

My ubuntu 12.04 solution is install the ruby1.9.1-full version, that can resolve this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

you can execute command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

to select the altiernative ruby which you have installed.
and then, execute below commands to finish the octopress deploy:

```
git clone https://github.com/erizhang/octopress.git octopress
cd octopress/
sudo gem install bundler
sudo gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'
bundle install
rake install
```

below commands you can find from octopress deploy guideline page:

```
rake setup_github_pages
sudo rake setup_github_pages
sudo rake generate
sudo rake deploy
```

Hope it's helpful for you, thanks

Comment: This also just worked on a fresh Terminal.com Debian 7.0 (Wheezy) terminal. Hurray! (Just started playing with Terminal.com. Hurray!)

Answer (score 20):

I was installing Octopress too and got the same problem as yours. After checking the `mkmf.log` file I figured out that gcc-4.2 had not been found. I Even installed xcode with the command line tools. It worked when I made a symlink like this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
$ bundle install
```

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I acquired gcc-4.2 in the first place. To do that: `brew tap homebrew/dupes
 && brew install apple-gcc42`. [Credit.](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion)

Comment: If apple-gcc42 is missing Install the Command Line Tools (Xcode 4.3). 
XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads, Click the Components button, and then click Install next to the "Command Line Tools".

Comment: Works for Mavericks. OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 19):

I fixed this issue by running

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

as described in [this blog post](http://tarashish.com/blog/2013/02/02/fixing-mkmf-load-error-ubuntu/).

Comment: This solved the problem for me on Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such.  Not having the ruby-dev package installed seems to be a common cause for this install error.

Comment: Solved the issue for me as well

Answer (score 6):

For **Ubuntu 14.04** simply do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

Should work for 13.10 and 13.04 too. (Not tested)

Comment: I'd do that as `install ruby1.9.3`.  The space in there allows for some confusion.

Comment: @EricAnderson The space has been removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it apears you are not using rvm for managing your ruby installation. I think best would be to try rvm, here's a very good guide, you can stop without installing rails: [ruby with rvm](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/)

Then simply

```
$gem install RedCloth
```

Unmanaged ruby gems are a pain, I try to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Upgrade to ruby 2.0 fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.0 /usr/bin/ruby
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem2.0 /usr/bin/gem
sudo gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also have the `build-essential` package installed. You can check using

> `dpkg -l | grep build-essential`

or simply install it without checking

> `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

For me on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, after making sure `build-essential` is installed, the `bundle install` command works/builds fine also with Ruby 1.9.3.